# represent my sql query in laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an application tha i want it to make bookings but i'am having trouble making my Eloquent query

I have two modals "Booking.php" and "Room.php"  my bookings migrations table is as follows

```
Schema::create('bookings', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('phone');
        $table->integer('time_in');
        $table->integer('room_id');
        $table->integer('time_out');
        $table->string('days');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->integer('expiry_status'); /*expiry status 0->expired 1->not expired*/
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and my rooms migrations table is as follows

```
    Schema::create('rooms', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('room_no');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

in my view i have got inputs for satrt of reservation(time_in) and end of reservation(time_out) now if there is a reservation that does not end before or start after the reservation we want, the room is considered busy therefore i do not want to show that room show those rooms for my reservation dates.
My problem is I want to know the rooms  available between my reservation dates,Can someone help me to write the eloquent to get the available rooms from the above table structures. I'm using mysql as the database engine. Thanks in advance.

I found this query to be useful but how to i implement it in the form of Eloquent model

```
SELECT r.id
FROM rooms r
WHERE r.room_id NOT IN (
SELECT b.room_id FROM bookings b
WHERE NOT (b.time_out   < '2012-09-14T18:00'
           OR
           b.time_in > '2012-09-21T09:00'))
 ORDER BY r.room_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create subselects and advanced where conditions in Laravel Eloquent.
This script worked for me. I tried to build it for your schema.

```
DB::table('rooms')
->whereNotIn('room_id', function($query)
 {
    $query->select('room_id')
        ->from(with(new Booking)->getTable())
        ->where(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('time_out', '<', '2012-09-14T18:00')
                ->orWhere('time_in', '>', '2012-09-21T09:00');
        });
 })
->orderBy('room_id')
->get();
```

https://gist.github.com/DengoPHP/d3e95441a7b9e27299b7

Comment: While this link might answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.